# Accessing Python List Type

Tags: python, list

I write a code that has str data

```
def characters(self, content):
    self.contentText = content.split()
# self.contentText is List here
```

I am sending self.contentText list to another module as:

```
self.contentText = Formatter.formatter(self.contentText)
```

In this method, I am writing below code:

```
remArticles = remArticles = {' a ':'', ' the ':'', ' and ':'', ' an ':'', '&  nbsp;':''}

for i in remArticles:
  print type(contentText) 
  print "1"
  contentText = contentText.replace(i, remArticles[i])
  print type(contentText)
```

I get error:

```
contentText = contentText.replace(i, remArticles[i])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

If I change it to:

```
for i in remArticles:
  contentText = contentText.pop(i)
```

I get below error:

```
contentText = contentText.pop(i)#replace(i, remArticles[i])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Comment: Well... what  is `contentText`... I don't see it nowhere...

Comment: Why are you calling pop on a string?

Comment: You are overwritting the `contentText` in the loop... so, its type is changing.

Comment: @PeterWood I was trying out different things. I have edited my question, may be it will make more sense to you now?

Comment: See the answer by @Frerich Raabe

Answer (score 3):

`contextText` is indeed a list and as such has no `replace` method. The second error is caused by the fact that you overwrite `contextText` with the return value of `contextText.pop(i)` (which returns the popped value), so that after the first iteration of the loop `contextText` is no longer a list but a string.

Comment: To further clarify, in the first instance when I sau contextText = contentText.pop(i), it is still a list.

In the next iteration, after looping, contentText has another NEW value. Are you saying then after overwriting it becomes String?

Is my understanding right? If yes, why does that happen. Its same list value again right?

Comment: @Rakanid: The [documentation for `list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) explains: "Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in the list." Note that it does *not* return a list, it returns the removed value.

Comment: Got it. So what can I do to remove a word that's in the dict? Even the list.remove() does not seem to help

Comment: @Rakanid You should consider asking a separate question for that - I'm not sure I understand. If you want to remove all elements from `list` which don't exist in the dict `remArticles` then I'd suggest a list comprehension: `list = [s for s in list if s not in remArticles]`.

Comment: You nailed it. Let me try your suggestion

Comment: Can you please confirm if `remArticles` has to be List or is it fine if it is Dict. If it is Dict, do I need to set it like:

`list = [s for s in list if s not in remArticles[key]]`

Comment: Also what is it exactly doing?

Comment: @Rakanid Please open new questions if you have follow-up questions instead of asking in the comments.