# Python List Comprehensions - Comparing with Dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension

I write a code that has str data

```
def characters(self, content):
    self.contentText = content.split()
# self.contentText is List here
```

I am sending `self.contentText` list to another module as:

```
self.contentText = Formatter.formatter(self.contentText)
```

In this method, I am writing below code:

```
remArticles = remArticles = {' a ':'', ' the ':'', ' and ':'', ' an ':'', '&  nbsp;':''}

contentText = [i for i in contentText if i not in remArticles.keys()]
```

But it is not replacing. Is it that remArticles should be list and not dict

But I tried replacing it with list too. It wouldn't simply replace.

ofcourse with list, below will be the code:

```
  contentText = [i for i in contentText if i not in remArticles]
```

This is continuation from [Accessing Python List Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538422/accessing-python-list-type)

Initially I was trying:

```
for i in remArticles:
  print type(contentText) 
  print "1"
  contentText = contentText.replace(i, remArticles[i])
  print type(contentText)
```

But that threw errors:

```
contentText = contentText.replace(i, remArticles[i])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Can you please include an example input and an example output? It's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: There seems be no problem with the code as such. Can you please give an example of the `content`?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus - It's pretty straight forward. I will have a list `['Dinakar','a','{','Indiana']`. This is input.

Output is `['Dinakar','Indiana']`. Remove `'a'` and `'{'`. Hope that explains

Comment: @ManojAwasthi - Just gave an example. Hope that helps

Comment: so your problem is that your dict actually contains `spaces` e.g. `<space>a<space>` and not `a`..

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear but if your goal is to convert a string to a list, remove unwanted words, and then turn the list back into a string, then you can do it like this:

```
def clean_string(s):
    words_to_remove = ['a', 'the', 'and', 'an', '&nbsp;']
    list_of_words = s.split()
    cleaned_list = [word for word in list_of_words if word not in words_to_remove]
    new_string = ' '.join(cleaned_list)
    return new_string
```

This is how you could do the same without converting to a list:

```
def clean_string(s):
    words_to_remove = ['a', 'the', 'and', 'an', '&nbsp;']
    for word in words_to_remove:
        s = s.replace(word, '')
    return s
```

And if you wanted more flexibility in removing some words but replacing others, you could do the following with a dictionary:

```
def clean_string(s):
    words_to_replace = {'a': '', 'the': '', 'and': '&', 'an': '', '&nbsp;': ' '}
    for old, new in words_to_replace.items():
        s = s.replace(old, new)
    return s
```

Comment: What you have understood is correct<br/>

But yes, I guess that's what I gave too. <br/>
contentText = [i for i in contentText if i not in remArticles] <br/>
I just got deviated from actual issue. Hence re-writing. The data I am getting is already a list. Referring to your step, we can omit `list_of_words = s.split() `So I don't think I have to split it again<br/>

However it is not replacing...<br/>

Comment: For some reason it didn't work earlier and now I guess it is working.

Comment: I think it didn't work because of the problem noted by Manoj Awasthi -- you have spaces surrounding the keys in `remArticles` but your list of words in `contentText` probably does not contain any spaces.

Comment: I have content that will have spaces too. So that isn't the issue at all.

Comment: If you use `split` to turn a string into a list, all spaces will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your map contains spaces within the keys. Following code solves your problem:

```
[i for i in contentText if i not in map(lambda x: x.strip(), remArticles.keys())]
```